# First and second date from table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sequelpro

In SQL I am trying to extract the first and the second date from a table. I am using the query below which I formulated based on a number of posts I read on here about the same topic i.e. extracting the second date etc. But for some reason it does not give me the right answer and I don't understand why.

The table is called `motif_segmentvalue` and it has a column called `EntryDate` which I am interested in using to extract the dates. I wrote a small query for a particular user `5407` to see if I was getting the right result or not.

```
 select sv2.UserId, sv2.EntryDate, min(sv2.EntryDate)
 from motif_segmentvalue sv2
 where sv2.EntryDate  > (select MIN(sv3.EntryDate) from motif_segmentvalue sv3)
 and sv2.UserId = "5407"
```

The output that I get is:

```
 UserId   EntryDate             min(sv2.EntryDate)

  5407    2016-01-20 12:50:00   2016-01-20 12:50:00
```

Based on my data, this is incorrect and the "EntryDate" column should have a different date to the min(sv2.EntryDate) - it should have the second date. But for some reason, it does not. I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone provide hints on what I might be doing incorrectly? Am I wrongly expecting "EntryDate" to be the second date?

I have also tried many other users and both columns give the same date.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it using `ORDER BY` clause and `LIMIT` it for 2 rows only

Comment: Yup... I get the same result. The end goal is to run this on the whole database for all the users I have and limit doesn't work there, it just returns the first user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will get you what you want.

It has a 2050-01-01 date as backup for when there is no second date

```
select sv2.UserId, min(sv2.EntryDate) as first
, min(if(sv2.EntryDate=mindate,'2050-01-01', sv2.EntryDate)) as second
from motif_segmentvalue sv2
join (
    select sv3.UserId, min(sv3.EntryDate) as mindate 
    FROM motif_segmentvalue sv3
    WHERE sv3.UserId = "5407"
) as temp ON temp.UserId = sv2.UserId
WHERE sv2.UserId = "5407"
```

update: 
This will fetch the second date, instead of the next datetime.

```
select sv2.UserId, min(sv2.EntryDate) as first
, min(if(date(sv2.EntryDate)=mindate,'2050-01-01', sv2.EntryDate)) as second
from motif_segmentvalue sv2
join (
    select sv3.UserId, min(date(sv3.EntryDate)) as mindate 
    FROM motif_segmentvalue sv3
    WHERE sv3.UserId = "5407"
) as temp ON temp.UserId = sv2.UserId
WHERE sv2.UserId = "5407"
```

Comment: I just updated it. I created it with MAX in mind, but saw afterwards I should use MIN :)

Comment: Great! Thanks, works perfectly... Just one question... What if I have a user who has multiple times for the same date... so for `5407` I have two times on that date, is there a way to skip to just the next date and not just the next time point?

Comment: You may consider changing '2050-01-01' to null... probably no query we write today will last 30 years, but you never know :)

Comment: Does it have a unique id column @MaheenSiddiqui ? In case it has, you could CONCAT this field to 'mindate' in the inner sub query and compare against this in you outer select

Comment: @Johan no... UserId is as unique as it gets... I used DATE and it seems to be fine...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I'd build that query in a few steps.

First of all, get the absolute minimum

```
select  UserId, min(EntryDate)
from    motif_segmentvalue
where   UserId = "5407" 
group by UserId
```

Then get the next minimum (using the query above)

```
select  UserId, min(EntryDate)
from    motif_segmentvalue
where   UserId = "5407" and
        EntryDate > (
            select  UserId, min(EntryDate)
            from    motif_segmentvalue
            where   UserId = "5407" 
            group by UserId
        )
group by UserId
```

Finally join the two

```
select  t1.UserId, t1.min_1, t2.min_2
from    (
            select  UserId, min(EntryDate) as min_1
            from    motif_segmentvalue
            where   UserId = "5407" 
            group by UserId
        ) t1
join    (
            select  UserId, min(EntryDate) as min_2
            from    motif_segmentvalue
            where   UserId = "5407" and
                    EntryDate > (
                        select  UserId, min(EntryDate)
                        from    motif_segmentvalue
                        where   UserId = "5407" 
                        group by UserId
                    )
            group by UserId
        ) t2
on      t1.UserId = t2.UserId
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *  FROM motif_segmentvalue sv2
WHERE sv2.UserId = "5407" 
ORDER BY EntryDate ASC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: `Top` doesn't work in my mysql... I have tried limit 2 after order by but I still don't get the right thing. I need a column which lists the second date...

Comment: For MySQL, I believe that LIMIT is used, rather than TOP